# How to SSH a git repository after already cloned with https?

Tags: git

I have a repository that I have already cloned on my computer using `https`. I want to set up this repository as `ssh` so that I don't have to enter in my username and password every time I git push.

Any suggestions on how I can convert this `https` cloned repository to `ssh` without having to actually re-clone it, so that I may avoid entering my credentials all the time?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a pretty good documentation from GitHub:
https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh

In short, this should do it:

```
git remote set-url origin user@example.com:PATH/REPOSITORY
```

Comment: For example with a GitHub repo `johndoe/helloworld` use `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:johndoe/helloworld.git`. The postfix `.git` seems to be optional.

Answer (score 6):

You should remove your HTTP remote (for example with `origin`):

```
git remote remove origin
```

and add the SSH remote instead

```
git remote add origin user@example.com:path/to/project.git
```

You will then also have to set the branch's remote again with

```
git push -u origin master
```

or

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin master
```