# Cannot push after changing from https to ssh

Tags: git, ssh, https, migrate

I had a repository, which was cloned using HTTPS, and I wanted to "convert" that to ssh, for not to write username and passwords each time I push.

So using info from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55246165/how-to-ssh-a-git-repository-after-already-cloned-with-https) page, I somehow moved to ssh.

But after that `git push` stopped working, in the terminal, the cursor just blinks...
I tried moving backwards to https, but nothing changes.
Can anyone tell the reason why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if your SSH url works:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

(Assuming a GitHub remote here): if the authentication succeeds, then your local user does have the relevant `~/.ssh/id_rsa` private key.

Comment: thanks, i tried this with another repository, for previous one i just deleted remote repository and created a new one